Could not find 'bundler' (2.5.7)
MacOS user here. I am trying to build a website hosted on github. Followed the instructions from this website but used a different jekyll theme. When I try to preview my website locally via
bundle exec jekyll serve
I get the following error:

Could not find 'bundler' (2.5.7) required by your /Users/ad/Desktop/Website/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run bundle update --bundler.
To install the missing version, run gem install bundler:2.5.7

When I try bundle update --bundler, it says

You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.

My bundler version is Bundler version 1.17.2.
How can I get bundle exec jekyll serve to run?
I tried to install a second version of ruby using homebrew since I read that one cannot update the preinstalled MacOS version of ruby. ruby-install -V gives ruby-install: 0.9.3.
However, chruby -h gives zsh: command not found: chruby.
When I use open -e ~/.zshrc, I get

source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
chruby ruby-3.3.3.

Please help...

Don't use homebrew for installing Ruby when you intend to use chruby / ruby-install. Likewise, stick to one Ruby version manager. Having multiple version managers installed (e.g. chruby and rbenv) usually won't work well.

@Stefan How do I uninstall chruby then?

brew uninstall chruby or if you installed it manually see README.md#uninstall

There are different ways, but what I do is:

Install https://brew.sh (a package manager for macOS)

Install rbenv (a version manager for different ruby versions)
brew install rbenv
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"' > ~/.zshrc


Open new terminal and cd into your repository

Create a file called .ruby-version in your repo with the contents 3.3.3 (or whatever ruby version you want to run)

rbenv install (after that, ruby -v should print 3.3.3)

bundle install (install jekyll and its dependencies)

bundle exec jekyll serve (start your dev server)



Thanks! After running bundle exec jekyll serve, there are various error messages, e.g. Jekyll 4.3.3   Please append --traceto theserve command                       for any additional information or backtrace. Unsurprisingly, opening "localhost:4000" gives "Safari Can't Open the Page". Any ideas?

With the same code that runs fine on GitHub Pages? Probably, it means you got ruby/bundler/jekyll working correctly, but there are just some errors in the code of your website? what errors?

I figured it out myself. I had to install a few things. Now it works!
