The livereload does not work and there is no automatic refresh when changing HTML files
I want to live reload website usign jukyll. I am using windows 11; I have ruby 3.3.5. I am working on the following repository: https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io. When I build with bundle exec jekyll s --livereload or jekyll serve -l -o the site builds as expected. I get the following confirmation:
C:\Users\K\Documents\GitHub\B-M.github.io>bundle exec jekyll serve --open-url --livereload --livereload-port 35730
Configuration file: C:/Users/K/Documents/GitHub/B-M.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/K/Documents/GitHub/B-M.github.io
       Destination: C:/Users/K/Documents/GitHub/B-M.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: enabled
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 2.529 seconds.
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/Users/K/Documents/GitHub/B-M.github.io'
LiveReload address: http://127.0.0.1:35730
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
        LiveReload: Browser connected

When I access to http://127.0.0.1:4000/: I can see my web but when I do some changes, they does not appears. and when I access http://127.0.0.1:35730 always shows me that message:  This port only serves livereload.js over HTTP.
I want to do automatic reload to changes locally !
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem 'jekyll'
  gem 'jekyll-feed'
  gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
  gem 'jemoji'
  gem 'webrick', '~> 1.8'
end

gem 'github-pages'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem "jekyll-sass-converter", "1.5.2"

and this is the config.yml
# Welcome to Jekyll!
#
# This config file is meant for settings that affect your entire site, values
# which you are expected to set up once and rarely need to edit after that.
# For technical reasons, this file is *NOT* reloaded automatically when you use
# `jekyll serve -l -H localhost`. If you change this file, please restart the 
# server process.
timezone: UTC
livereload: true



# Basic Site Settings
locale                   : "en-US"
title                    : "Bahi / Site Title"
title_separator          : "-"
name                     : &name "Your Name"
description              : &description "personal description"
url                      : https://academicpages.github.io # the base hostname & protocol for your site e.g. "https://mmistakes.github.io"
baseurl                  : "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. "/blog"
repository               : "academicpages/academicpages.github.io"

# Site Author - The following control what appear as part of the author content on the side bar.
#               If a field is blank the icon and link will not appear, otherwise it will be shown.
#               Additional customization can be done by editing /_includes/author-profile.html
author:
  # Biographic information
  avatar           : "profile.png"
  name             : "a"
  pronouns         : # example: "she/her"  
  bio              : "Short biography for the left-hand sidebar"
  location         : "Earth"
  employer         : "Red Brick University"
  uri              : # URL
  email            : "none@example.org" 

  # Academic websites
  arxiv            : # URL - Update with the correct link to your profile
  googlescholar    : "https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=PS_CX0AAAAAJ"
  impactstory      : # URL
  orcid            : "http://orcid.org/yourorcidurl"
  semantic         : # URL
  pubmed           : "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=john+snow"
  researchgate     : # URL

  # Repositories and software development
  bitbucket        : # Username - Update with your username on the site
  codepen          : # Username
  dribbble         : # Username
  github           : "academicpages"
  kaggle           : # Username  
  stackoverflow    : # User number or user number and name (i.e., use "1" or "1/jeff-atwood")    

  # Social media
  bluesky          : "bsky.app" # Replace this with you Bluesky username
  facebook         : # Username
  flickr           : # Username
  foursquare       : # Username
  goodreads        : # Username
  google_plus      : # Username
  keybase          : # Username
  instagram        : # Username
  lastfm           : # Username
  linkedin         : # Username
  mastodon         : # URL
  medium           : # URL
  pinterest        : # Username
  soundcloud       : # Username
  steam            : # Username
  telegram         : # URL
  tumblr           : # Username
  twitter          : # Username for X / Twitter
  vine             : # Username
  weibo            : # Username
  wikipedia        : # Username
  xing             : # Username
  youtube          : # Username
  zhihu            : # Username

# Publication Category - The following the list of publication categories and their headings
publication_category:
  books:
    title: 'Books'
  manuscripts:
    title: 'Journal Articles'    
  conferences:
    title: 'Conference Papers'

# Site Settings
teaser                   :  # filename of teaser fallback teaser image placed in /images/, .e.g. "500x300.png"
breadcrumbs              : false # true, false (default)
words_per_minute         : 160
future                   : true
read_more                : "disabled" # if enabled, adds "Read more" links to excerpts
talkmap_link             : false #change to true to add link to talkmap on talks page
comments:
  provider               : # false (default), "disqus", "discourse", "facebook", "google-plus", "staticman", "custom"
  disqus:
    shortname            :
  discourse:
    server               : # https://meta.discourse.org/t/embedding-discourse-comments-via-javascript/31963 , e.g.: meta.discourse.org
  facebook:
    appid                :
    num_posts            : # 5 (default)
    colorscheme          : # "light" (default), "dark"
staticman:
  allowedFields          : ['name', 'email', 'url', 'message']
  branch                 : "gh-pages" # "master", "gh-pages"
  commitMessage          : "New comment."
  filename               : comment-{@timestamp}
  format                 : "yml"
  moderation             : true
  path                   : "_data/comments/{options.slug}"
  requiredFields         : ['name', 'email', 'message']
  transforms:
    email                : "md5"
  generatedFields:
    date:
      type               : "date"
      options:
        format           : "iso8601" # "iso8601" (default), "timestamp-seconds", "timestamp-milliseconds"
atom_feed:
  hide                   : false     # change to true to hide the RSS feed in the footer
  path                   : # blank (default) uses feed.xml


# SEO Related
google_site_verification :
bing_site_verification   :
alexa_site_verification  :
yandex_site_verification :


# Social Sharing
twitter:
  username               : &twitter
facebook:
  username               :
  app_id                 :
  publisher              :
og_image                 :  # Open Graph/Twitter default site image
# For specifying social profiles
# - https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/social-profiles
social:
  type                   : # Person or Organization (defaults to Person)
  name                   : # If the user or organization name differs from the site's name
  links: # An array of links to social media profiles


# Analytics
analytics:
  provider               :  "false" # false (default), "google", "google-universal", "google-analytics-4", "custom"
  google:
    tracking_id          :


# Reading Files
include:
  - .htaccess
  - _pages
  - files
exclude:
  - "*.sublime-project"
  - "*.sublime-workspace"
  - .asset-cache
  - .bundle
  - .github
  - .jekyll-assets-cache
  - .sass-cache
  - assets/js/_main.js
  - assets/js/plugins
  - assets/js/vendor
  - CHANGELOG
  - Capfile
  - config
  - Dockerfile
  - Gemfile
  - Gruntfile.js
  - gulpfile.js
  - LICENSE
  - local
  - log
  - node_modules
  - package.json*
  - Rakefile
  - README
  - tmp
  - vendor
keep_files:
  - .git
  - .svn
encoding: "utf-8"
markdown_ext: "markdown,mkdown,mkdn,mkd,md"


# Conversion
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
lsi: false
excerpt_separator: "\n\n"
incremental: false


# Markdown Processing
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  hard_wrap: false
  auto_ids: true
  footnote_nr: 1
  entity_output: as_char
  toc_levels: 1..6
  smart_quotes: lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo
  enable_coderay: false


# These settings control the types of collections used by the template
collections:
  teaching:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:path/
  publications:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:path/
  portfolio:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:path/
  talks:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:path/


# These settings control how pages and collections are included in the site
defaults:
  # _posts
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: posts
    values:
      layout: single
      author_profile: true
      read_time: true
      comments: true
      share: true
      related: true
  # _pages
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: pages
    values:
      layout: single
      author_profile: true
  # _teaching
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: teaching
    values:
      layout: single
      author_profile: true
      share: true
      comments: true
  # _publications
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: publications
    values:
      layout: single
      author_profile: true
      share: true
      comments: true
  # _portfolio
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: portfolio
    values:
      layout: single
      author_profile: true
      share: true
      comment: true
  # _talks
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: talks
    values:
      layout: talk
      author_profile: true
      share: true


# Sass/SCSS
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: compressed # http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style


# Outputting
permalink: /:categories/:title/
# paginate: 5 # amount of posts to show
# paginate_path: /page:num/
timezone: Etc/UTC # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones


# Plugins
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-gist
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jemoji

# Mimic GitHub Pages with --safe
whitelist:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-gist
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jemoji


# Archives
#  Type
#  - GitHub Pages compatible archive pages built with Liquid ~> type: liquid (default)
#  - Jekyll Archives plugin archive pages ~> type: jekyll-archives
#  Path (examples)
#  - Archive page should exist at path when using Liquid method or you can
#    expect broken links (especially with breadcrumbs enabled)
#  - <base_path>/tags/my-awesome-tag/index.html ~> path: /tags/
#  - <base_path/categories/my-awesome-category/index.html ~> path: /categories/
#  - <base_path/my-awesome-category/index.html ~> path: /
category_archive:
  type: liquid
  path: /categories/
tag_archive:
  type: liquid
  path: /tags/
# https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-archives
# jekyll-archives:
#   enabled:
#     - categories
#     - tags
#   layouts:
#     category: archive-taxonomy
#     tag: archive-taxonomy
#   permalinks:
#     category: /categories/:name/
#     tag: /tags/:name/


# HTML Compression
# - http://jch.penibelst.de/
compress_html:
  clippings: all
  ignore:
    envs: development


what ruby version are you using? You may want to create a .ruby-version file in your repo and use something like rbenv, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78666132/could-not-find-bundler-2-5-7/78666172#78666172

for what it's worth, I tried your repo with ruby 3.3.1 on macOS 14.7 with Firefox 131 and live-reloading worked when I edited the _includes/_footer.html file. (You should see a WS websocket connection in your browser's network dev tools.)

@mb21 I have ruby 3.3.5 and I am using windows

I did not see WS websocket connection in my browser's network dev tools

Did the browser load the liverload script? Check dev tools. A missing WS connection sounds like it did not load the required JavaScript file. Perhaps a lead to something to troubleshoot.

Also try different browsers (in incognito mode or at least with extensions disabled). Or perhaps it's a Windows thing...

ah, have you installed the wdm gem? I think it's required under windows, see https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/livereload-option-not-working-on-windows-10/5769/2

Not an answer but after more than 10 years as a ruby developer in a windows shop,  I would highly recommend taking a few minutes (that's really all it takes) to set up WSL. This simple step will save you countless hours of trying to figure out why things don't work quite right in windows.

I am also on Windows. I use --force-polling and it works. I got the solution from this Github issue
This flag forces Liquid to use polling rather than inotify. So, note that it is more CPU intensive.
